Is there something wrong with my session.run() usage?
I'm using Tensorflow.net, Numsharp and TensorFlow.Keras in a C# Winforms on .NET 4.8 app, and trying to make a q learning neural network. School makes us use Winforms and it's painful honestly.
How is the way that I'm using session.run() wrong in this case?
public void Train(NDArray currentState, int action, float reward, NDArray nextState, bool done)
{
    var graph = session.graph.as_default();

    simMenu.LogMessage($"Training started with currentState: {currentState}, action: {action}, reward: {reward}, nextState: {nextState}, done: {done}");

    try
    {
        currentState = np.reshape(currentState, new int[] { 1, stateSize });
        currentState = currentState.astype(np.float32);

        // Get the Q-values for the current state
        var qValuesCurrent = session.run(output, new FeedItem(state, currentState));
        
        float currentQValue = qValuesCurrent.ToArray<float>()[action];

        // Get the Q-values for the next state
        nextState = np.reshape(nextState, new int[] { 1, stateSize });
        nextState = nextState.astype(np.float32);
        
        var qValuesNext = session.run(output, new FeedItem(state, nextState)); //here is where the error occurs
     
        float maxFutureQValue = np.max(qValuesNext.ToArray<float>());

        // Calculate the target Q-value
        float targetQValue = reward;

        if (!done)
        {
            targetQValue += discountFactor * maxFutureQValue;
        }

        // Update the Q-value using the Q-learning formula
        var qValuesArray = qValuesCurrent.ToArray<float>();
        qValuesArray[action] = currentQValue + learningRate * (targetQValue - currentQValue);
        var updatedQValues = np.array(qValuesArray).reshape(1, actionSize);

        // Train the model
        session.run(optimizer, new FeedItem(state, currentState), new FeedItem(qTarget, updatedQValues));
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        simMenu.LogMessage($"An error occurred during training: {ex.Message}");
        throw;
    }
}

When I ran, I get this error

System.NotImplementedException: ''

and the log messages are:

Session and graph initialized successfully.
Training started with currentState: [140.0723, 30.92329, 30.92329, 51.61395, 40.36087], action: 2, reward: 1, nextState: [140.1722, 30.92329, 30.92329, 51.61395, 40.50206],
done: False
An error occurred during training:

watch of the variables at the error
The whole function is listed here:
using NumSharp;
using Tensorflow;
using static Tensorflow.Binding;
using System;
using Coursework;

public class QLearningAgent
{
    private readonly int stateSize;        // Size of the state
    private readonly int actionSize;       // Number of actions
    private readonly float learningRate;   // Learning rate
    private readonly float discountFactor = 0.99f; // Discount factor for future rewards
    private readonly float explorationProbability; // Epsilon for exploration
    private readonly Session session;      // TensorFlow session
    private readonly Tensor state;         // Placeholder for the current state
    private readonly Tensor qTarget; // Placeholder for the target Q-values
    private readonly SimMenu simMenu;

    private Tensor output;                 // Output layer for Q-values
    private Operation optimizer;
    
    public QLearningAgent(int stateSize, int actionSize, float learningRate, SimMenu simMenu, float explorationProbability = 0.1f)
    {
        this.stateSize = stateSize;
        this.actionSize = actionSize;
        this.learningRate = learningRate;
        this.explorationProbability = explorationProbability;
        this.simMenu = simMenu;

        // TensorFlow graph construction
        var graph = tf.Graph().as_default();

        // Initialize session
        session = tf.Session(graph);
        session.run(tf.global_variables_initializer()); //session.run() works fine here

        this.state = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape: new int[] { -1, stateSize });
        this.qTarget = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape: new int[] { -1, actionSize });

        // Define the neural network structurek
        var hidden = tf.keras.layers.Dense(24, activation: "relu").Apply(state); // Hidden layer
        this.output = tf.keras.layers.Dense(actionSize, activation: "linear").Apply(hidden); // Output layer for Q-values

        // Loss and optimizer
        var loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(output - qTarget));
        this.optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learningRate).minimize(loss);

        simMenu.LogMessage("Session and graph initialized successfully.");
    }

    public int GetAction(NDArray currentState)
    {
        // Epsilon-greedy action selection
        if (new Random().NextDouble() < explorationProbability)
        {
            // Explore: select a random action
            return new Random().Next(actionSize);
        }
        else
        {
            // Exploit: select the action with the highest Q-value
            var graph = session.graph.as_default();

            // Get the Q-values for the current state
            var feedDict = new FeedItem(state, currentState);
            var qValues = session.run(output, feedDict); // Session.run() doesn't work here either however it goes to Train() before GetAction()
            var qValuesArray = qValues.ToArray<float>(); // Convert Tensorflow.NumPy.NDArray to a float array
            return np.argmax(np.array(qValuesArray)); // Return the index of the action with the highest Q-value
        }
    }

    public void Train(NDArray currentState, int action, float reward, NDArray nextState, bool done)
    {
        var graph = session.graph.as_default();

        simMenu.LogMessage($"Training started with currentState: {currentState}, action: {action}, reward: {reward}, nextState: {nextState}, done: {done}");

        try
        {
            currentState = np.reshape(currentState, new int[] { 1, stateSize });
            currentState = currentState.astype(np.float32);

            // Get the Q-values for the current state
            var qValuesCurrent = session.run(output, new FeedItem(state, currentState));
            
            float currentQValue = qValuesCurrent.ToArray<float>()[action];

            // Get the Q-values for the next state
            nextState = np.reshape(nextState, new int[] { 1, stateSize });
            nextState = nextState.astype(np.float32);
            
            var qValuesNext = session.run(output, new FeedItem(state, nextState));
         
            float maxFutureQValue = np.max(qValuesNext.ToArray<float>());

            // Calculate the target Q-value
            float targetQValue = reward;

            if (!done)
            {
                targetQValue += discountFactor * maxFutureQValue;
            }

            // Update the Q-value using the Q-learning formula
            var qValuesArray = qValuesCurrent.ToArray<float>();
            qValuesArray[action] = currentQValue + learningRate * (targetQValue - currentQValue);
            var updatedQValues = np.array(qValuesArray).reshape(1, actionSize);

            // Train the model
            session.run(optimizer, new FeedItem(state, currentState), new FeedItem(qTarget, updatedQValues));
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            simMenu.LogMessage($"An error occurred during training: {ex.Message}");
            throw;
        }
    }
}

I tried checking all the types and compatibility of state and nextstate, I also tried to reshape them to make sure that they are the NDArray of the same length and type. It should take 5 inputs.
My describing of the problem might not be the best or most comprehensive as this is my first post, thank you for taking the time to read. If you need any more information just ask!
